# How do you find the deepest node (steps) - Xpath - php - xml -

Tags: php, xml, xpath, nodes

Greetings

How do you find the deepest node? 
So for this example, String would be the deepest node:

and the result that I want is **5**

> ```
> <org.olat.course.nodes.STCourseNode>                    0
>    <ident>81473730700165</ident>                        1
>    <type>st</type>
>    <shortTitle>General Information</shortTitle>
>        <moduleConfiguration>                            2
>           <config>                                      3
>              <entry>                                    4
>                 <string>allowRelativeLinks</string>     5           <---
>                 <string>false</string>
>              </entry>
>              <entry>
>                 <string>file</string>
>                 <string>/kgalgemeneinformatie.html</string>          
>              </entry>
>              <entry>
>                 <string>configversion</string>
>                 <int>3</int>
>              </entry>
>              <entry>
>                 <string>display</string>
>                 <string>file</string>
>              </entry>
>           </config>
>        </moduleConfiguration>
>     </org.olat.course.nodes.STCourseNode>
> ```

Note: I use php, **xpath**

Other possibilities are also welcome :)

Kind regards

Dieter Verbeemen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With XPath 2.0 you could write a single XPath expression I think, as `max(descendant::*[not(*)]/count(ancestor::*))`. With XPath 1.0 you could find the node with XSLT as the host language as in

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select="descendant::*[not(*)]">
    <xsl:sort select="count(ancestor::*)" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
    <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
      <xsl:value-of select="count(ancestor::*)"/>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

If you use PHP as the "host" language for XPath you can probably write something similar with a loop over `descendant::*[not(*)]`, the elements not having any child elements, and computing `count(ancestor::*)` for each of them and storing the maximum value.

[edit] Here is some attempt at PHP:

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$leafElements = $xpath->query("descendant::*[not(*)]");
$max = 0;

foreach ($leafElements as $el) {
  $count = $xpath->evaluate("count(ancestor::*)", $el);
  if ($count > $max) {
    $max = $count;
  }
}
// now use $max here
```