# How to implement recursion in XSL?

Tags: xslt

I have a XML data document which has nested tags called 'folio'. The maximum level it can such nested tag is 4. I need to recursively process each folio until I reach a level where there is no nested folio and print the contents.

I am not sure of how to do recursion in XSL. Here is a sample doc. Can sombody help ?

Thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
    <reporting:root xmlns:reporting="http://www.xyzcorp.net/reporting">
      <reporting:default0 reporting:type="Portfolio">
        <reporting:header>
          <reporting:configuration>
        <reporting:columns>
          <reporting:column reporting:group="instrument" reporting:name="Ident" reporting:tag="ident" reporting:type="int"/>
          <reporting:column reporting:group="prices" reporting:name="Last (Time)" reporting:tag="lastTime" reporting:type="string"/>
          <reporting:column reporting:group="noGroup" reporting:name="RIC" reporting:tag="ric" reporting:type="string"/>
          <reporting:column reporting:group="instrument" reporting:name="Reference" reporting:tag="reference" reporting:type="string"/>
          <reporting:column reporting:group="result" reporting:name="Currency" reporting:tag="currency" reporting:type="string"/>
        </reporting:columns>
      </reporting:configuration>
    </reporting:header>
    <reporting:window reporting:Id="36674" reporting:level="0" reporting:name="MY_PORTFOLIO" reporting:parentId="11991">
      <reporting:folio>
        <reporting:folioid>1234</reporting:folioid>
        <reporting:folio>
          <reporting:folioid>9876</reporting:folioid>
          <reporting:line reporting:Id="67520135" reporting:level="1" reporting:name="INTERNATIONAL BUSINESS MACHINES CORP" reporting:parentId="36674" reporting:positionType="0">
            <reporting:ident>643633</reporting:ident>
            <reporting:reference>IBM.USD</reporting:reference>
            <reporting:currency>USD</reporting:currency>
          </reporting:line>
          <reporting:line reporting:Id="67520179" reporting:level="1" reporting:name="GENERAL ELECTRIC CO" reporting:parentId="36674" reporting:positionType="0">
            <reporting:ident>643635</reporting:ident>
            <reporting:ric>GE.N</reporting:ric>
            <reporting:reference>GE.USD</reporting:reference>
            <reporting:currency>USD</reporting:currency>
          </reporting:line>
        </reporting:folio>
      </reporting:folio>
    </reporting:window>
  </reporting:default0>
</reporting:root>
```

Comment: Seems similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9890097/how-do-you-find-the-deepest-node-steps-xpath-php-xml.  Just needs a bit of tweaking to limit to 'folio' nodes...

Answer (score 5):

The normal default mode of processing in XSLT is to write a template rule for each element that does something and calls apply-templates to process its children:

```
<xsl:template match="folio">
  <do something>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </do something>
</xsl:template>
```

This is naturally recursive: whenever you process an element, you invoke processing on its descendants.

So you don't really need to learn how to do recursion in XSLT; you almost need to learn how NOT to do it.