# Using PowerShell, what's the shorest way to add a child three levels deep?

Tags: xml, powershell

Given the following XML:

```
<greatGrandParent>
</greatGrandParent>
```

I want to end up with:

```
<greatGrandparent>
  <grandparent>
    <parent>
      <child />
    </parent>
  </grandparent>
</greatGrandparent>
```

In PowerShell, what's the easiest way to add the last node (child)? Can it be done using just the path /greatGrandarent/grandparent/parent/child? Can it be done without getting greatGrandparent, appending grandparent, appending parent to grandparent, etc.?

Below is a sample of what I've used to automatically build missing nodes in the path. The CreateNode method cannot take a "/" in the path, so, it cannot be used to build the nodes.

```
$path = "C:\xmlfile1.xml"

$content = '<greatGrandParent></greatGrandParent>'
[System.Xml.XmlDocument] $xd = new-object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$xd.LoadXml($content)

$nodes = @("greatGrandParent", "grandParent", "parent", "children", "add[@key='John']", "add")

$finalNode = $null
$currentNode = $xd
$currentXpath = ""

foreach ($nodeName in $nodes) {
    $currentXpath += "/" + $nodeName
    $finalNode = $xd.SelectSingleNode($currentXpath)
    if (!$finalNode) {
        if ($nodeName -eq $nodes[$nodes.Count-2]) {
            $finalNode = $xd.CreateNode("element", $nodes[$nodes.Count-1], "")
            $currentNode.AppendChild($finalNode)
            break
        }
        else {
            $finalNode = $xd.CreateNode("element", $nodeName, "")
            $currentNode.AppendChild($finalNode)
        }
    }
    $currentNode = $finalNode
}

$xd.Save($path)

Write-Host "Complete."
```

Comment: Please share your attempt at a solution, this is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 0):

You can [use xpath to find the deepest node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9890097/how-do-you-find-the-deepest-node-steps-xpath-php-xml) and then add a node.